# Tomcat starting Error while i am using GoogleAPI

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, google-plus

i have some problem with GoogleAPI.

Tomcat was working fine but when i wrote those one, my tomcat dose not work properly.

```
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
```

this is my controller.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;

import airbnb.dao.CustomerDAO;
import airbnb.vo.CustomerVO;


public class CustomerController extends HttpServlet{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "Client_id";

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {




    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String mode = req.getParameter("mode");
        //String customerCheck = req.getParameter("customerName");
        System.out.println("customerCheck");





        String id_token = req.getParameter("id_token");
        System.out.println("id_token"+id_token);

        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();//*
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();//*


        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
                // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
                //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
                .build();


            GoogleIdToken idToken = null;
            try {
                idToken = verifier.verify(id_token);
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                if (idToken != null) {
                    Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

                    // Print user identifier
                    String userId = payload.getSubject();
                    System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

                    // Get profile information from payload
                    String email = payload.getEmail();
                    boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
                    String name = (String) payload.get("name");
                    String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
                    String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
                    String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
                    String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

                    // Use or store profile information
                    // ...
                     System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
                      System.out.println("email: " + email);
                      System.out.println("emailVerified: " + emailVerified);
                      System.out.println("name: " + name);
                      System.out.println("pictureUrl: " + pictureUrl);
                      System.out.println("locale: " + locale);
                      System.out.println("familyName: " + familyName);
                      System.out.println("givenName: " + givenName);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
                }   
    }
}
```

this is error.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Airbnb]]
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>           Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Airbnb]]
>               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>               ... 6 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
>               at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
>               at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
>               at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
>               at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:136)
>               at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
>               at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
>               at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
>               at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
>               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>               ... 6 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
>               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
>               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>               ... 19 more   11 21, 2017 10:16:54 午前 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>       重大: A child container failed during start
>       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           ... 6 more 11 21, 2017 10:16:54 午前 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       重大: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
>       org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           ... 7 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           ... 9 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           ... 11 more

conditions: jdk 1.8, Tomcat 8.5

please help me to solve this error.

if you want more information, please tell me. I will upload it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this line :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport
```

You need to add `google-api-client` jar file in Tomcat classpath from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.client)

Comment: Thank for your answer. But i already added **google-api-client-1.23.0.jar** still it does not work.

Comment: in which location is the file ? can you add it to libs folder of tomcat

Comment: i added *WEB-INF/lib*  and  *Java Resources/Libraries*. i added both of them. Do i have to add any other locations?

Comment: no , just make sure this file is in WEB-INF/lib ONLY , not in both the places , and you should be through